# Using react native build on device red screen is coming .Android error “Could not connect to the server” on start of app.

Tags: react-native

I am new in react native language first time run the build on the physical device the red screen is comming how to resolve this

Comment: Hey pls check out this link... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40903211/react-native-red-screen-error

Comment: Is your react native packager running?

Comment: @Nithin i already check that links but there are no running code on that page

Comment: what error is showing in that screen , take screen shot and post.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a bundle error.

You can run command react-native-start. Then open this link in browser

http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=true&minify=false

It will bundle the package with development server.

or It may be an issue with adb not running

Answer (score 0):

Only applicable for physical mobile device

incase you are still our of luck ... follow these steps

usually its port forwarding which causes this
so ensure you have already executed
adb reverse tcp:5000 tcp:6000

(OVER here your port number can be same or different depending upon how do you run your program, in my case i keep both of the same)

And if your issue is solved.

identify your machine ip address
goto mobile device (ensure wifi is turned on and you are on same network)
open any browser and see whether your ip is accessible by using following url

{ip address}:{port}

Example: 10.98.1.1:9001

If you see page can't be displayed, Do following -

Still run the application on device which will show red color error screen 
Shake the device
Goto Dev settings
Open Debug server host & port for device
Enter
localhost:{port number} instead of ip address

You are done.